# How to efficiently insert this 2D array into my database with laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am struggling to get my head around how I can insert this array into my database. I have a 2D array being sent as a PUT request (I think its actually an object $request). The array contains information about a personal training plan. The first dimension in the array specifies the day of the week. The second specifies which values belong to which category/column and which day. In my current example I am only submitting exercise plans for Monday which again is denoted by the first level in the array as 1 Tuesday would be 2 and so on. I have the exercise_plans table filling correctly as that is not 2D. It's the exercise_plan_details table that I can't figure out.

$request->reps[ 1][0] would be the amount of reps for the first exercise on Monday.

$request->reps[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljzJK.png)][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljzJK.png)] would be the second amount of reps for the 2nd exercise on Monday

$request->reps[ 2][0] would be the amount of reps for the first exercise on Tuesday.

$request->reps [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBKsY.png)][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljzJK.png)] would be the second amount of reps for the 2nd exercise on Tuesday

Monday might not have any exercises while Friday might have 8.

I hope you understand and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the array printed using $request->all()

```
 array(8) {
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "DAOV7rwCjZhnC8cZMmYRsPRLEjnMIZi8CERAwibD"
  ["title"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["queue"]=>
  string(12) "Add Exercise"
  ["exerciseList"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "4"
    }
  }
  ["reps"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "11"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "44"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "77"
    }
  }
  ["sets"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "22"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "55"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "88"
    }
  }
  ["weight"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "33"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "66"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "99"
    }
  }
  ["_method"]=>
  string(3) "PUT"
}
```

Another view of the array being sent as a request object

[image]

Database:

[image]

Here is how I am manually inserting one row

```
$array = $request->all();

var_dump($array);

$post = new ExercisePlan();
$post->trainerID = Auth::user()->id;
$post->name = $request->input('title');
$post->save();

$details = new ExercisePlanDetails();
$details->planID = $post->id;
$details->day = "Monday";
$details->exerciseID = $request->exerciseList[1][0];
$details->reps = $request->reps[1][0];
$details->sets = $request->sets[1][0];
$details->priority = "1";
$details->weight = $request->weight[1][0];
$details->save();
```

This manual way was just for testing but I think I need a double for each to get all of the data into the db? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First what I would do is set up a relationship between `ExercisePlan` and `ExercisePlanDetails` using `details` method and add `$fillable` property to be able to use mass assignment with the `create` statement later on.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class ExercisePlan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'trainerID',
        'name'
    ];

    public function details(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ExercisePlanDetails::class, 'planID', 'id');
    }
}
```

Make sure that your `ExercisePlanDetail` model also has `$fillable` property set

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExercisePlanDetails extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'day',
        'exerciseID',
        'reps',
        'sets',
        'priority',
        'weight'
    ];
}
```

Now from within the controller, in order to create multiple `ExercisePlanDetails` records for a given plan we could first generate an array of data for each detail record and use `createMany` method on the relationship to add them all with a single call

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ExercisePlan;
use App\Utilities\Date;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class ExerciseController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $plan = ExercisePlan::create([
            'trainerID' => $request->user()->id,
            'name' => $request->input('title')
        ]);

        $details = collect($request->exerciseList)
            ->flatMap(function(array $exercises, int $dayId) use ($request) {
                return $this->parseEntry(
                    new Collection($exercises), $dayId, $request
                );
            })->toArray();

        $plan->details()->createMany($details);

        return new JsonResponse([], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

    protected function parseEntry(Collection $exercises, int $dayId, Request $request): array
    {
        return $exercises->map(function(int $value, int $index) use ($dayId, $request) {
            return [
                'day' => Date::day($dayId),
                'exerciseID' => $value,
                'reps' => $request->reps[$dayId][$index],
                'sets' => $request->sets[$dayId][$index],
                'priority' => 1,
                'weight' => $request->weight[$dayId][$index],
            ];
        })->toArray();
    }

}
```

To get a `day` as string I've created a simple utility class with the static method `day`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Utilities;

class Date
{
    public static function day(int $dayId): string
    {
        switch($dayId) {
            case 1:
                return 'Monday';
            case 2:
                return 'Tuesday';
            case 3:
                return 'Wednesday';
            case 4:
                return 'Thursday';
            case 5:
                return 'Friday';
            case 6:
                return 'Saturday';
            case 7:
                return 'Sunday';
            default:
                throw new \Exception('Invalid day');
        }
    }
}
```

I've set the following route

```
Route::put('/exercise', 'ExerciseController@store')->name('exercise.store');
```

And the following test, which passes

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\ExercisePlan;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExerciseTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * @var \App\User
     */
    protected $user;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($this->user);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function adds_exercise_plan_with_plan_details()
    {
        $response = $this->put(route('exercise.store'), [
            'title' => 'Fake title',
            'queue' => 'Add Exercise',
            'exerciseList' => [
                1 => [3, 3, 4],
                5 => [4, 5, 6],
            ],
            'reps' => [
                1 => [11, 44, 77],
                5 => [12, 45, 78],
            ],
            'sets' => [
                1 => [22, 55, 88],
                5 => [23, 56, 89],
            ],
            'weight' => [
                1 => [33, 66, 99],
                5 => [34, 67, 100],
            ]
        ]);


        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_CREATED);

        $plan = ExercisePlan::first();

        $this->assertEquals('Fake title', $plan->name);
        $this->assertEquals($this->user->id, $plan->trainerID);

        $this->assertCount(6, $plan->details);


        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'day' => 'Monday',
                'exerciseID' => 3,
                'reps' => 11,
                'sets' => 22,
                'priority' => 1,
                'weight' => 33
            ],
            $plan->details->get(0)->only(['day', 'exerciseID', 'reps', 'sets', 'priority', 'weight'])
        );

        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'day' => 'Monday',
                'exerciseID' => 3,
                'reps' => 44,
                'sets' => 55,
                'priority' => 1,
                'weight' => 66
            ],
            $plan->details->get(1)->only(['day', 'exerciseID', 'reps', 'sets', 'priority', 'weight'])
        );

        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'day' => 'Monday',
                'exerciseID' => 4,
                'reps' => 77,
                'sets' => 88,
                'priority' => 1,
                'weight' => 99
            ],
            $plan->details->get(2)->only(['day', 'exerciseID', 'reps', 'sets', 'priority', 'weight'])
        );

        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'day' => 'Friday',
                'exerciseID' => 4,
                'reps' => 12,
                'sets' => 23,
                'priority' => 1,
                'weight' => 34
            ],
            $plan->details->get(3)->only(['day', 'exerciseID', 'reps', 'sets', 'priority', 'weight'])
        );

        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'day' => 'Friday',
                'exerciseID' => 5,
                'reps' => 45,
                'sets' => 56,
                'priority' => 1,
                'weight' => 67
            ],
            $plan->details->get(4)->only(['day', 'exerciseID', 'reps', 'sets', 'priority', 'weight'])
        );

        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'day' => 'Friday',
                'exerciseID' => 6,
                'reps' => 78,
                'sets' => 89,
                'priority' => 1,
                'weight' => 100
            ],
            $plan->details->get(5)->only(['day', 'exerciseID', 'reps', 'sets', 'priority', 'weight'])
        );

    }
}
```

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I fixed that by adding the relationship. Now there it created two rows in my table with just the timestamps and planID. Even though it should have created 4. 2 Monday and 2 Tuesday.

Comment: Did you add `details()` method to the `ExercisePlan` model as per my instructions above?

Comment: I did as you were replying. See my updated reply above. Here is a screenshot. https://gyazo.com/ac08c2adb63d55130901be9f0a5e708d

Comment: I'm going to re-create the whole scenario locally and update when I've run some tests.